# Double angle bracket in atom using auto-complete

Tags: html, autocomplete, intellisense, atom-editor

Can anyone please help me?

When I use autocomplete in atom in html files an extra angle bracket gets created. Like this- (In this I used autocomplete to autocomplete the textarea tag but it created an extra angle bracket)

```
<form>
      <input id="formEntryName" type="text" placeholder="Entry Name" name="entryName" required>
      <br><br>
      <<textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
```

can someone please help me!!!!!!
This is very annoying when I am writing the HTML as I have to go back all the way and first delete the angle bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you don't need to write the angle brackets at all. For example, typing `textarea` and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand to `<textarea></textarea>`.